# Laravel delete file in app folder (root)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, unlink

How to delete files from Laravel app directory (not the public directory but the one in the root)?

I tried :

```
\Storage::Delete('App\file.php');
\Storage::Delete('\App\file.php');
\File::Delete('App\file.php');
\File::Delete('\App\file.php');
unlink ('\App\file.php');
```

Nothing works.

**UPDATE:**
The file is in something like `\App\folder\folder\file.db`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not specifying an absolute path then what is used is the current working directory (the value that [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) would return). Usually, that's the `/public` directory and not the actual project root.

You need to specific an absolute path using the Laravel helpers:

```
\File::delete(app_path('file.php'));
```

**Note:** You can't use the `\Storage` helpers because they are limited to only work within the app storage folder.